# Redirection URL not being shown in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to do a 3rd party authentication. I have a login page where user clicks on the login button and user is redirected to the 3rd party authorization page where on successful login user is redirected to a page of our choice, for e.g. In my case I have set it to `http://localhost/redirection` and then the request token is appended to it, that I would like to read. But now what happens is when user is redirected to something like `http://localhost/redirection?request_token=asdfasfdas`, it wouldn't work because user is not authenticated and automatically redirected to login page and I don't want to keep the redirection page directly accessible or any other endpoints. I just want to know what is an ideal way of doing this in react. I have my routes defined like this:

```
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/redirection" element={<Redirection />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

This is preventing the redirected url to be shown in the browser and automatically redirects the user to login page. I need the request token from the redirected url and also want to prevent direct access to the endpoints. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you are asking. Can you [edit] to clarify what any one specific issue is?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is happening in the app when the URL path is `"/redirection?request_token=asdfasfdas"`? Is the `Redirection` component being rendered? It's unclear what any "authentication" has to do with that route since it is unprotected. We still need better details. See [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I need to implement something like this login -> https://web.sensibull.com/login
where user can log in through their brokers and after successful login they are redirected back to their website. If you could just hint me on how its ideally done in react since I'm fairly new to react, that would be great.

Comment: What part do you specifically need help with? Landing on `"/"`, getting navigated to `"/login"` and navigated/redirected to external URL "web.sensibull.com/login" to authenticate? Or that part is working and the user is redirected back to `"/redirection?request_token=...."`? So far you've only showed us your routes, so if there are issues external to these we should see what *that* code is doing.

Comment: @DrewReese right now user gets redirected to "/redirection?request_token=...." but automatically gets redirected to /login page since he is not authenticated.

Comment: What is doing that redirection though? `"/redirection"` isn't a protected route so I don't see how it would bounce a user unless it's something in the `Redirection` component doing it. Can you share that component?

Comment: @DrewReese the solution by Mearaj worked and now its working but now redirection route is directly accessible. can i somehow protect the route of redirection such that it works only when authentication is going on and not when someone types it in the browser url.

Comment: How is that even possible? You are clearly using `react-router-dom@6`, their answer doesn't seem correct to me at all since RRDv6 doesn't have a `Redirect` component and the v6 `Route` component doesn't render anything but other `Route` components as children. Sure, you can protect any routes you want under any conditions you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you are using React Router version 5.
If that's the case you need to make the following changes, because currently every path matches "/" by default.
Adding exact keyword, will make sure that match is exact.

```
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/redirection" element={<Redirection />} />
    <Route path="*"><Redirect to="/" /></Route>
  </Routes>
);
```